# Why is my API note returning all items from the model?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to return all items from the `User` model when a certain API endpoint is navigated to.

Here is my Flask route:

```
@app.route('/user/all', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    output = []

    for user in users:
        output = {'id': user.id, 'username': user.username, 'email': user.email}
    return jsonify(output)
```

Here is my `User` model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    api_token = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    todos = db.relationship('Todo', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')
```

But whenever I navigate to `/user/all` in Postman or another API testing tool. I only get one user back.

Why is this? There is definitely more users in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are updating in the same dict

```
@app.route('/user/all', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    output = []

    for user in users:
        output.append({'id': user.id, 'username': user.username, 'email':user.email})
    return jsonify(output)
```